# how to fix the getAttribute when clicking a item for change link in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

****list.component.html***

```
<div *ngFor="let data of temperature">
<div (click)="navigate(data)">
                <div id="{{ 'roomChart-' + i }}" style="height: 210px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
lineChart() {
const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById(`roomChart-${index}`) as HTMLCanvasElement);
            this.option = {
              tooltip: {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer: {
                  animation: false
                },
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.8)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#ccc',
                padding: 10,
                textStyle: {
                  color: '#000'
                },
                formatter: function (prm: any) {
                  let rec = prm[0].name.slice(0, 10) + '<br/>' + prm[0].name.slice(11, 19) + '<br/>';

                  for (let x = 0; x < prm.length; x++) {
                    if (prm[x].axisIndex !== 1) {
                      rec += prm[x].marker + ' ' + prm[x].seriesName + ': '
                        + prm[x].data + _this.units['Celcius'] + '<br/>';
                    } else {
                      rec += prm[x].marker + ' ' + prm[x].seriesName + ': '
                        + prm[x].data + '%' + '<br/>';
                    }
                  }
                  return rec;
                }
              },
              ...this.echart.roomChart,
              dataZoom: [{
                type: 'inside',
                show: false,
                bottom: 10,
                width: '84%',
                xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
                zoomOnMouseWheel: false
              },
              {
                type: 'slider',
                bottom: 10,
                show: false,
                width: '84%',
                xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
                zoomLock: true
              }],
              ...this.echart.roomChart.xAxis[0].data = newData[0].date.map((str: any) => {
                return format(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');
              }),
              ...this.echart.roomChart.xAxis[1].data = newData[0].date.map((str: any) => {
                return format(str, 'YYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');
              }),
              ...this.echart.roomChart.xAxis[0].axisLabel.formatter = ((data: any) => {
                return format(data, 'hh:mm a');
              }),
              series: [
                {
                  name: 'Temerature',
                  data: newData[0].temperature,
                  type: 'line',
                  itemStyle: {
                    color: 'rgba(0, 101, 144, 1)'
                  },
                  areaStyle: {
                    color: 'rgba(0, 101, 144, 1)'
                  },
                  markPoint: {
                    type: 'Pin',
                    data: [
                      {
                        type: 'max',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: 'rgba(0, 101, 144)'
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        type: 'min',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: 'rgb(110, 151, 204)'
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  smooth: true
                },
                {
                  name: 'Humidity',
                  data: newData[0].humidity,
                  type: 'line',
                  itemStyle: {
                    color: 'rgba(132, 219, 255, 1)'
                  },
                  areaStyle: {
                    color: 'rgba(132, 219, 255, 1)'
                  },
                  markPoint: {
                    type: 'Pin',
                    data: [
                      {
                        type: 'max',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: 'rgba(132, 219, 255)'
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        type: 'min',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: 'rgba(194, 237, 255)'
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  smooth: true,
                  xAxisIndex: 1,
                  yAxisIndex: 1
                }
              ]
            };

            chart.setOption(this.option);
}


    navigate(data: any) {
    const roomName = encodeURIComponent(data.sensor);
    if (data) {
      this.router.navigate([`/dashboard/room`], {
        queryParams: { room: roomName }
      });
    }
  }
```

I have an error which is the `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`.
when the lineChart still loading then clicking the division. I'm getting this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`

How to fix the error Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null.

But when the chart are all loaded there's no error, but when still loading and click the division/item while loading I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementById`. This is outside of Angular's world, that's why it can't find the element you're trying to select.

**Solution 1 : ngAfterViewInit**

First, you have to wait for Angular to draw the view ( = generate the HTML), *then* you can use `getElementById` on what's been generated.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 echarts.init(document.getElementById(`roomChart-${index}`) ...
}
```

But that's still hacky, as everything that will happen is outside of Angular's world.

**Solution 2 :**

Use [Echarts for Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts) :)

Comment: you mean the <div echarts [option]="">?

Comment: if I have an array how do I apply it on the <div echarts [option]="">? is this correct ``` <div echarts [option]="'{{roomChart'+i}}"> ?

Comment: cause my chart is multiple array.

Comment: `you mean the <div echarts [option]="">?` What does that question refer to? `is this correct <div echarts [option]="'{{roomChart'+i}}"> ?` Probably not, this doesn't look like an options object. Best is to [read the doc](https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/api-doc/).

Comment: <div echarts [option]="data">

Comment: it doesn't display the echarts

Comment: what I did is 
                    ```<div echarts [options]="data" [autoResize]="true" style="height: 280px;"></div>```

Comment: I'm getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.. <div echarts [options]="option">